# Rails: delayed_job mail not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm trying to use delayed_job gem https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job in Rails 3.2 to send a mail in the background.

I installed the gem

```
 gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

I generated the table and ran the migrations, as instructed

```
$ rails generate delayed_job:active_record
$ rake db:migrate
```

Noting that there are special instructions for mailers in Rails 3

```
     # without delayed_job
Notifier.signup(@user).deliver

# with delayed_job
Notifier.delay.signup(@user)
```

I did

```
 def send_welcome_email

    #UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver  <-- original code that worked

   UserMailer.delay.welcome_email(self)        

  end
```

but the mail isn't sending. It was working before I tried to use delayed_job...

Can someone clarify for a novice...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you start at least 1 `delayed_job` worker?

```
rake jobs:work
```

Actually, when you call `delay`on an object, you are only *queuing* a job. Which means that a new entry will be created inside the `DelayedJob` table that contains all the metadata associated with your job.

So you still need something that will browse all your `DelayedJob`entries and run them one by one and that thing is the rake task (worker) shown above.

For production, it depends where you are deploying your application. On Heroku you only have to specify how many workers (`Worker dynos`) you need and they will start automatically.

Comment: no, i didn't. so I'm responsible for doing that? How do I get that to run in production without me triggering it? Can you explain? thanks

Comment: Yes you are responsible for starting your workers. Are you using Heroku for production?

Comment: also see the "Running Jobs" section on the readme at https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: @AmokraneChentir yes, I'm using Heroku for production

Comment: @Michael Ok see my edit. You only have to specify how many workers you need (1 is ok to start with) on the resources page.

Comment: @AmokraneChentir I mean, do I still have to do RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start  after setting the worker?

Comment: @AmokraneChentir but this kinda sucks now, 1 worker is $35 per month and this is just a starter app with likely no traffic :(

Comment: @Michael Sorry, nothing you can do about it apart from moving away form Heroku or use an alternative solution to process your delayed jobs.

Comment: If your jobs do not need to start processing lightning fast, you can sign up for hirefire.io.

Comment: The hobby dyno, worker bundle exec rake jobs:work is only $7.00/month